# Android: Alignment of four squares

Tags: java, xml, android, layout

I am trying to align four equally sized *squares* on an Android Screen & I have now tried what feels like a million different approaches, yet none of them seem to work :(.

What I've got at the moment is the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:id="@+id/MasterLayout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:background="#FFFFFF">
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/mainlay" android:background="#444444" android:layout_weight="0.2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="0dip">
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"  android:background="#BBBBBB" android:padding="0dip">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView1" android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="5px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:src="@drawable/bigbox_new"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView2" android:layout_marginLeft="5px" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:src="@drawable/bigbox_new"></ImageView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="0dip">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView3" android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="5px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:src="@drawable/bigbox_new"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView4" android:layout_marginLeft="5px" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:src="@drawable/bigbox_new"></ImageView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This basically does the job. However, every one of those four Images has a huge padding above and under it. How do I get rid of that? Or do I need to use a different Layout type alltogether?

To help illustrate my problem, here's a picture.
On the left is what I got, on the right is what I need.
[Image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.a839cd1b5a.png)

Thank you very much!

Cheers, Markus!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `layout_weight` from your TableRows and set their `layout_height` to `wrap_content`. Then add an empty TableRow below them with `layout_height` set to `fill_parent`.

Comment: Thank you! This trick with the fill_parent layout was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the scaleType as centerCrop, if the image size is greater then this will do the trick for you. But this is not the best way to do it, better would be to change the image resources.

HTH !

Comment: Hello Karan.

Thanks for your tip. However it seems that my description wasn't too clear (and especially the picture); I need the squares to remain squares. They should be as big as possible in a 2x2 grid. But the remaining space on the screen must not be between the four squares, but below them on the bottom of the screen.

Do you have a pointer for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ImageView height to fill_parent, I think that should do the trick. Anyway, it would help if your XML properties were split in lines, it's hard for the rest of us to read a single line of properties.

Also, why do you place a TableLayout inside a LinearLayout? Unless you have more elements inside that Linear, you can get rid of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not have the desired effect. Thank you anayway for your time!
@ Code; you are right. I have now restructured it to several lines.