# Android - draw squares in xml

Tags: android

I'd like to draw three squares side-by-side in xml, so that they fill the screen horizontally (minus a margin of 12 dp on each side).  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843087/android-alignment-of-four-squares) it seems possible to do this messily with table layouts, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.  Here's my attempt using nested LinearLayouts, which draws rectangles which fill the entire screen vertically but otherwise does what I'm looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The parent LinearLayout should include android:wieghtSum="3"

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) android:weightSum "defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children."  So this wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best solution is to create a custom view component with an overridden `onMeasure()`:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the three internal linearlayouts' android:layout_width="match_parent" to "wrap_content".

I just did a test using the following xml code. Notice that, there are two changes from your version:

1 I changed match_parent to wrap_content of the three children layouts.
2 Since I don't have your background image, I just use three different colors for background.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff121212" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff676767" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffababab" >
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I get this screen:

[image: my test result]

So if have changed match_parent to wrap_content but not work, I guess your background image is too big.

Also, turning to the understanding about layout_weight. Layout_weight doesn't decide element's size, it only works after each element has required neccessary size from parent layout, then parent layout assign rest of size to each element according to layout_weight.

Comment: This does absolutely nothing since layout_weight is already set in the horizontal direction for all rectangles.  Even if layout_weight were not there, this would collapse all the rectangles horizontally, rather than making a square.

Comment: My background image is a rectangle <shape>.  However, it doesn't matter what the size of the image is, though, since it will distort to fill the layout.   Here, the layouts are rectangular, so the background image will not be square no matter what size it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for margins and height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Because there's no content to wrap vertically, this just collapses my rectangles to 4dp horizontal lines.  Also, putting the margins into the sub-layouts functionally changes the UI, since it makes the parent LinearLayout fill the entire screen.